# c pointers issue. compiler error

Tags: c

I`m struggling for a few hours with this issue :

```
char szKeyMap[MAX_ALPNUM_KEYS][CHAR_PER_KEY]= {"0- +%",  "1QZ.\\", "2ABC&",  "3DEF%",  "4GHI*",  "5JKL/", "6MNO~", "7PRS^", "8TUV[", "9WXY]",  "*,'\":", "#=:$?" };



getkbd_entry(h_clock,insertPin,pinBuff,0,NUMERIC ,szKeyMap,sizeof(szKeyMap), 6 , 4);
```

and the getkbd_entry prototype is :

```
int getkbd_entry(int h_clock, char *msg, char *outbuf, unsigned wait,
unsigned type, char szKeyMap[][CHAR_PER_KEY],
int KeyMapSize, int va_alist, ...);
```

the errors i am getting in the compiler :

```
"C:\Bin\test.c", line 90: Warning:  #167-D: argument of type "c
har *" is incompatible with parameter of type "signed char *"
  getkbd_entry(h_clock,insertPin,pinBuff,0,NUMERIC ,szKeyMap,sizeof(szK
eyMap), 6 , 4);

                                 ^
"C:\Bin\test.c", line 90: Error:  #167: argument of type "signe
d char (*)[6]" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
  getkbd_entry(h_clock,insertPin,pinBuff,0,NUMERIC ,szKeyMap,sizeof(szK
eyMap), 6 , 4);
```

any help is much appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: It's C code, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is `CHAR_PER_KEY` a `#define`d constant? I'm a bit baffled that the compiler interprets `char szKeyMap[][CHAR_PER_KEY]` as a `char*` in the second message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because `szKeyMap` is `char**` instead of `char*`

Comment: Any idea how to go around it ?
The problem is that this code is an example code from a software dev. kit...
Pretty strange

Comment: Problem was apparently solved this way : 

    getkbd_entry(h_clock,insertPin,pinBuff,0,NUMERIC ,szKeyMap[6],sizeof(szKeyMap), 6 , 4);


Quote from the manual :

> By default, in the ACT library, CHAR_PER_KEY is defined as 6. Hence
> the application can have five chars per key in the keymapping array

It was just guesswork for me, I can't really understand it

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and added a trivial few lines to make it compile, and it compiles fine with gcc -Wall for me.  However, gcc -Wall will produce effectively the same error messages that you're seeing if you don't match "char" vs. "unsigned char" vs. "signed char".  This seems a little counter intuitive, since "char" must be either signed or unsigned, but double-check that your string definitions exactly match as it relates to signed, unsigned, or unspecified, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was apparently solved this way :

```
getkbd_entry(h_clock,insertPin,pinBuff,0,NUMERIC ,szKeyMap[6],sizeof(szKeyMap), 6 , 4);
```

Quote from the manual :

> By default, in the ACT library, CHAR_PER_KEY is defined as 6. Hence
>   the application can have five chars per key in the keymapping array

It was just guesswork for me, I can't relly understand it..